# FAILED: No config file 'alembic.ini' found

Tags: python, alembic

I tried to change in Alembic but when I try to run Alembic current I got error. I'm new in alembic, please tell me why I get this error and how can I solve it?

I can see `alembic.ini` in migration folder and also revision identifiers, used by Alembic and everything seems fine.

```
$alembic current
No handlers could be found for logger "alembic.util"
  FAILED: No config file 'alembic.ini' found, or file has no '[alembic]' section
```

`20c921506336_.py`:

```
"""empty message

Revision ID: 20c921506336
Revises: None
Create Date: 2015-01-30 16:28:38.981023

"""

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = '20c921506336'
down_revision = None

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


def upgrade():
    ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('user',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('name', sa.String(length=50), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('email', sa.String(length=50), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('age', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('bestfriend_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['bestfriend_id'], ['user.id'], ),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
    )
    op.create_index(u'ix_user_age', 'user', ['age'], unique=True)
    op.create_index(u'ix_user_email', 'user', ['email'], unique=True)
    op.create_index(u'ix_user_name', 'user', ['name'], unique=True)
    op.create_table('friends',
    sa.Column('user_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('friend_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['friend_id'], ['user.id'], ),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['user_id'], ['user.id'], )
    )
    ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_table('friends')
    op.drop_index(u'ix_user_name', table_name='user')
    op.drop_index(u'ix_user_email', table_name='user')
    op.drop_index(u'ix_user_age', table_name='user')
    op.drop_table('user')
    ### end Alembic commands ###
```

Comment: Was this ever solved? Neither of these answers work for me.

Answer (score 23):

You must `cd` to the directory that has the `alembic.ini` to run the `alembic` command, that is, the `alembic.ini` must be found in the current working directory; or you can specify the config file location with `alembic -c path/to/alembic.ini`.

And it seems that your alembic ini is broken, you ought to have `script_location` in there, thus if your migrations are in the `alembic` subdirectory, `alembic.ini` should read something like:

```
[alembic]
script_location = alembic

# Logging configuration
[loggers]
keys = root,sqlalchemy,alembic

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = WARN
handlers = console
qualname =

[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine

[logger_alembic]
level = INFO
handlers =
qualname = alembic

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s
datefmt = %H:%M:%S
```

The directory layout *must* be so that if your `script_location = alembic` it means that you have:

```
alembic.ini
alembic/   # this must match the script_location in alembic.ini
    env.py   # and this must be found at the script_location
    script.py.mako
    versions/
        20c921506336_.py
```

Comment: I did it but got this (venv)peg@peg:~/flask-Alembic/migrations$ alembic current
No handlers could be found for logger "alembic.util"
  FAILED: No 'script_location' key found in configuration.
@Antti Haapala

Comment: its the same in mine too so I have it the exact same @Antti Haapala

Answer (score 22):

For a deploy script doing something like this:

`ssh ... alembic upgrade head`

Antii's answer provides the direct answer which is the -c option:

`ssh ... alembic -c /path/to/alembic.ini upgrade head`

However then you may get like me:

`FAILED: Path doesn't exist: 'alembic'.  Please use the 'init' command to create a new scripts folder.`

Alembic is failing to interpret your intention for `script_location` in `alembic.ini`. Usually you run alembic from the directory with `alembic.ini` and alembic is able to interpret your `script_location` as a relative path.

However when you run it with a simple deploy script or otherwise from a different directory, it doesn't know where to look and it does not use the directory of `alembic.ini` to guess the location (as I think Antii suggested?).

If you look in the alembic source code [here](https://github.com/zzzeek/alembic/blob/d3676e25beb50ddc821937e4108d1c9535d4951e/alembic/util/pyfiles.py#L37), you can see that alembic wants either 1) an absolute path, 2) a package path or 3) a relative path from the working directory (the default case).

Therefore the second level of this answer is

### Option 1: Absolute path

(I haven't tested this!) Provide an absolute path to the alembic directory in `alembic.ini`. This doesn't work for me because the code becomes unportable:

```
...
script_location = /path/to/alembic/
...
```

### Option 2: Package path

Provide a package path in `alembic.ini`:

```
...
script_location = rootpackage:alembic  # or maybe rootpacakge.xyz:alembic
...
```

and of course it will actually need to be a package so the location with `alembic.ini` must have `__init__.py`.

### Option 3: Relative path

Instead of running alembic upgrade directly in your deploy script, make a bash script to `cd` to the right directory and then run it.

Comment: great answer. for the relative path issue use docker or another virtual env solution for cross-machine portability.

Comment: 7 years later, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, my `alembic.ini` file was in root project folder. And look like this

```
[alembic]
script_location = alembic
file_template = %%(year)d-%%(month).2d-%%(day)-2dT%%(hour).2d-%%(minute).2d-%%(second).2d_%%(rev)s
prepend_sys_path = .
version_path_separator = os
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://%(POSTGRES_USER)s:%(POSTGRES_PASSWORD)s@%(POSTGRES_HOST)s:%(POSTGRES_PORT)s/%(POSTGRES_DB)s
```

But when i run my pytest they was in `tests` filder and alembic try to find filder there. And after it raise exc. So i see two solution, create separate `alembic_pytest.ini` file. Or make some magic.

And i write fixture for migration.

```
ALEMBIC_INI_PATH = (Path(__file__).parent.parent / "alembic.ini").resolve()


@pytest.fixture
def migrated_postgres():
    al_config = AlembicConfig(ALEMBIC_INI_PATH)
    script_location = al_config.get_main_option("script_location")
    al_config.set_main_option("script_location", f"../{script_location}")
    with temp_db(conf.db_url) as db_url:
        alembic.command.upgrade(al_config, "head")
        yield db_url
```

As you se a get `script_location` field and modified it for parent folder.
It is not so perfect solution, but it work

P.S. I wish to have multiply path in `script_location` for situation like this

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default `working directory` for `pytest` to a specific value, meaning it will not change.

Click <kbd>Edit Configuration</kbd>:

[image]

then <kbd>Edit configuration templates...</kbd>:

[image]

From `Python Tests` select `pytest`:

[image]

and set your default Working Directory.